# How to loop in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to Angular, maybe is a fool question. 
I have a result from my `AngularJs` and I return an Array of values:

**This is the code:**

```
$scope.searchTitle = function () {

  $http.post('/svn/cms2/branches/create_function/cms/includes/find.php', { 
    name_title: $scope.title 
  })
  .success(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    $scope.resultName = result;
    $scope.ok = "we post";
  })
  .error(function (data, status) {
    console.log(data);
  });
};
```

And now i have the `resultName` in the html and i can see the result if i do this:

`<p>{{ resultName[0].article_titile }}</p>`

**Question:**

I want to display all the array. How can I display all?

**P.S.:**

I use this and it is not work

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in [3] | toRange" >
   <td>{{ resultName[i].article_titile }}</td>
</tr>
```

But is not working

Comment: <tr  ng-repeat="i in resultName | toRange" >
   <td>{{ i.article_titile }}</td>
</tr> reference: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-repeat.asp

Comment: It does not display again. my result in Dev tools is: 
(2) [{…}, {…}]
And in this  {...},{...} is my result of all array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an iterator variable (e.g. `result`) with your `resultName` array in your `ng-repeat`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in resultName | toRange" >
   <td>{{ result.article_titile }}</td>
</tr>
```